# Swiper continous loop without pause between sliding

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using this kind of configuration for swiper:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  speed: 2500,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: 1000,
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
  loop: true
});
```

This works fine so far. But is it possible with the swiper not to stop between each 3 slides? Right now there is always a break until the next 3 slides slide in. I'm looking for an infinite continuous looping slider option. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18):

Yes it's possible, big up [mariorendic](https://muut.com/i/swiper/feature-requests:continuous-autoplay)

```js
var swiperOptions = {
  loop: true,
  freeMode: true,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  grabCursor: true,
  slidesPerView: 7,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1,
    disableOnInteraction: true
  },
  freeMode: true,
  speed: 5000,
  freeModeMomentum: false
};

var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", swiperOptions);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #404449;
  
}

.swiper-container {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  margin: 60px;
}


.swiper-slide {
  width: 28vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear!important; 
  -o-transition-timing-function:linear!important;
  transition-timing-function:linear!important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/250/g);">1</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/260);">2</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/270);">3</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/270/y);">4</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/280/y);">5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/190/y);">6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(https://placekeanu.com/300/);">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tristanisginger/pen/dypxRbv

Comment: Thanks man, i also wanted to freeze on hover but i guess this should be ok for now ;)

Comment: try this: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1798

Answer (score 6):

you can fix this by adding this to your css *(you might need to play with the selectors a bit to this rule activated but it works)*:

```
.swiper-wrapper{
  transition-timing-function : linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no configurable way to set `autoplay: 0` because the conditional tests don't differentiate between a boolean value of `false` and a "falsy" value of `0`.

See https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/21d2a1da5b9b2e9610ec4005aad337a4af4d729f/src/js/core.js#L590. (Also check line 621)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and the reason was that pages of my swiper keep adding new elements (widgets in my case) every time when build method was called. The fix was to clear all lists of pages or items before adding elements to make sure you get rid of any previous elements from the last build.

Answer (score 0):

```
.swiper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

----------script------------------

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwipers", {
  spaceBetween: 20,
  direction: 'horizontal', 
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true, grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlidesBounds: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  simulateTouch: false,
  autoplay: {
    enabled: true,
    delay: 0,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  centerInsufficientSlides: true,

  speed: 15000,

  effect: 'slide',
  loopAdditionalSlides: 0,
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 4.5
    },
    576: {
      slidesPerView: 3.5
    }
  }
});
```